# XML : xPath - How can I Select all name nodes except empty nodes

Tags: xml, intellij-idea, xpath, xml-parsing

XML : xPath - How can I Select all name nodes except empty nodes. There is a xml file.

/* XML : xPath - How can I Select all name nodes except empty nodes.*/

```
<name></name> //empty node
```

```html
<foodlist>
        <fooditem>
                <name>Pizza</name>
                <cost>10€</cost>
        </fooditem>
        
        <fooditem>
                <name></name>
                <cost>5€</cost>
        </fooditem>
            
        <fooditem>
                <name>Burger</name>
                <cost></cost>
        </fooditem>
            
        <fooditem>
                <name>Cream</name>
                <cost></cost>
        </fooditem>
</foodlist>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```xml
//name[text()]
```

This will select all `name` elements, and then filter them to include only those which contain a text node.

Answer (score 0):

```
//fooditem[name != '']/name
```

will give you all none empty food names, you don't have to filter the empty ones